# Set Dynamic Attribute On Laravel Model

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

What i am trying to do is to set an attribute (active) on my model before first create it.

I want to avoid this hardcoded code with active user:

```
$user["firstname"] = "John";
$user["lastname"] = "Doe";
$user["active"] = 1;
UserModel::create($user);
```

I would like something like:

```
$user["firstname"] = "John";
$user["lastname"] = "Doe";
UserModel::active()->create($user);
```

Behind the scenes I want the active() method to set "active" column/attribute to 1.
How can i do it?

Comment: You could do that after the user is created if you want to use a method.

Comment: In this way, db called twice and I would like to avoid it if it's possible. Also, the active field is required in my DB Schema and there is no default value. I don't want to change the DB schema thats why I am looking for another solution. Thanks anyway!

Comment: You could also do `make()->active()->save()`

Comment: @Mike can you explain it further maybe with a code example or a function? thanks

Comment: Did you find a solution to this? if so it is good to post it for completeness.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `make` function of a model creates it in memory and does nit yet save it in the database

So what you could do is:

```php
$newUser["firstname"] = "John";
$newUser["lastname"] = "Doe";
UserModel::make($newUser)->activate()->save();
```

Your `active` function would look like this:

```php
public function activate()
{
    $this->active = 1;
    return $this;
}
```

This way the user is created in memory then set to active and then stored in the database.

If you want to do more with the user before you save it you can do it like this:

```php
$newUser["firstname"] = "John";
$newUser["lastname"] = "Doe";
$activeUser = UserModel::make($newUser)->activate();
//do stuff with $activeUser;
$activeUser->save();
```